# Passing Data to Component View Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

anyone
I got stuck when i try to pass data from the controller to the view blade. I am using laravel jetstream as the starter of my project and here is my code

**The Dashboard Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->data['currentAdminMenu'] = 'dashboard';

    return view('dashboard', $this->data);
}
```

**Main Layout**

```
<body class="antialiased">
<div id="app">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        @include('components.navbar')
        @include('components.sidebar')

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="main-content">
            <section class="section">
                <div class="section-header">
                    @isset($header_content)
                        {{ $header_content }}
                    @else
                        {{ __('Pages') }}
                    @endisset
                </div>

                <div class="section-body">
                    {{ $slot }}
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stack('modals')

@livewireScripts

@isset($script)
    {{ $script }}
@endisset
```

**The Sidebar**

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="{{ $currentAdminMenu == 'dashboard' ? $activeClass : '' }}"><a class="nav-link"
                href="{{ url('/dashboard') }}"><i class="fas fa-fire"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
        @foreach ($moduleAdminMenus as $moduleAdminMenu)
            <li class="menu-header">{{ $moduleAdminMenu['module'] }}</li>
            @foreach ($moduleAdminMenu['admin_menus'] as $moduleMenu)
                @can($moduleMenu['permission'])
                    <li class="{{ $currentAdminMenu == strtolower($moduleMenu['name']) ? $activeClass : '' }}"><a
                            class="nav-link" href="{{ url($moduleMenu['route']) }}"><i
                                class="{{ $moduleMenu['icon'] }}"></i> <span>{{ $moduleMenu['name'] }}</span></a>
                    </li>
                @endcan
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

**The Dashboard View**

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header_content">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <div class="section-header-breadcrumb">
        <div class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></div>
        <div class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Layout</a></div>
        <div class="breadcrumb-item">Default Layout</div>
    </div>
</x-slot>

<div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
    <x-jet-welcome />
</div>
```

when I am try run the code I got an error message like this `Undefined variable $currentAdminMenu`. but if I change the dashboard view with the `@extend` layout there is no error message anymore.
The question is how to pass `$this->data` from the controller to the dashboard view using `<x-app-layout>`. Could anyone here give me any suggestions or help me to solve this problem?
 Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Passing data into blade template

```
public function index()
{
    $this->data['currentAdminMenu'] = 'dashboard';

    return view('dashboard', [
        'data' => $this->data
    ]);
    // OR
    return view('dashboard')->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

variable by the name of data can be access inside blade

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs it should be a key value pair when passing data to view method. See
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views